# magento - 'invalid block type' exception

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6, magento-1.7

i created a new block in my own module of Customer, here's the config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nauba_Customer>
            <version>1.6.2.0.3</version>
        </Nauba_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <nauba_customer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Nauba_Customer</module>
                </setup>
            </nauba_customer_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <nauba_customer>
                <class>Nauba_Customer_Block</class>
            </nauba_customer>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <form_register>Nauba_Customer_Block_Form_Register</form_register>
                </rewrite>  
            </customer>
        </blocks>  
        <models>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer>Nauba_Customer_Model_Customer</customer>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>    
    </global>  
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Nauba_Customer before="Mage_Customer">Nauba_Customer</Nauba_Customer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>         
</config>
```

now i'm trying to call it in the home page, so i've specified it in the page.xml layout:

```
<!-- this is only the home page section -->


<page_homepage translate="label">
    <label>Homepage</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <!--reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/widgets.css</name></action>
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/print.css</name></action>                
        </reference-->

        <block type="page/html" name="category_links" template="page/html/category_links.phtml" />

        <block type="cms/block" name="homepage_slider_image_1" as="homepage_slider_image_1">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homepage_slider_image_1</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="homepage_slider_image_2" as="homepage_slider_image_2">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homepage_slider_image_2</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="homepage_slider_image_3" as="homepage_slider_image_3">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homepage_slider_image_3</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="homepage_slider_image_4" as="homepage_slider_image_4">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homepage_slider_image_4</block_id></action>
        </block>

        <block type="cms/block" name="homepage_event_banner_1" as="homepage_event_banner_1">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homepage_event_banner_1</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="homepage_event_banner_2" as="homepage_event_banner_2">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homepage_event_banner_2</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <block type="cms/block" name="homepage_event_banner_3" as="homepage_event_banner_3">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>homepage_event_banner_3</block_id></action>
        </block>
                    <block type="nauba_customer/list_ordercrosssell" name="ordercrosssell" as="ordercrosssell" template="nauba_customer/list/ordercrosssell.phtml">   

                    </block>
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/home.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>page_homepage</name></action>
    </reference>        
</page_homepage>
```

but it doesn't work when i call it in the home template with:

```
($this->getChildHtml('ordercrosssell'))
```

Also i've tried to create it by:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('ordercrosssell')
```

but it raise this exception '**invalid block type**'. any help?

Comment: Does your Block reside in `Nauba/Customer/Block/List/Ordercrosssell.php`? please check the path

Comment: @KalpeshMehta `app/code/local/Nauba/Customer/Block/List/Ordercrosssell.php`             path seems ok

Comment: did you specified your block path in config.xml? please show your config.xml code where you are defining blocks path.

Comment: which config.xml? i've already showed above module's config.xml

Comment: Okay that seems good. I hope you don't have any typo in classname as well as directory names.

Comment: give an example of this kind of problems...where i have to check?

Comment: you may check at http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/226398/#t317675 but it's having different problem

Comment: you can  even check this http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates for understanding from scratch

Comment: none of these helped...dont know what to check again now...

Comment: I guess there is some typo or the block is extended from the wrong class.

Comment: well but if i instantiate the block with: `$block = new Nauba_Customer_Block_List_Ordercrosssell();` it works, so it should be some XML mistake

Comment: Problem is that you are messing up namespace and module name. Your config XML is not good and Magento cannot find your block classes. I suggest you rebuild your module. Nauba is Namespace and Customer is module name as Mage is namespace and Customer is module name. Taking that into account, get inspiration from Mage_Newsletter which is a simple module and: use, let's say "MyCustomer" as module name (your whole module should then be Nauba_MyCustomer", modify your config XML and change your module's folders names.

Answer (score 2):

The createBlock() method would take in the whole block alias name (`nauba_customer/list_ordercrosssell`), not just `ordercrosssell`.  The reason that getChildHtml() can take in just `ordercrosssell` is because the child block's name is defined in the layout xml.

Not totally sure what may be wrong with your layout.xml, but you should probably drop the underscore in your aliases.  So instead of `nauba_customer` just go with `naubacustomer` or ideally something slightly shorter than that for ease of use.

I'm not 100% sure whether it's a problem or not but in general it's better to follow existing convention as @Herve mentioned with underscores vs. slashes in class aliases, b/c things can get a little hairy.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (Magento 1.9), if we forgot to use construct function in block PHP file then put it and the issue will be fixed:

```
 protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }
```

Comment: @Luke I Know, it is very late but still, I posted the answer because other developers may be searching or would be searching for this type of issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In some other cases (Magento 1.9), if we have wrong file permissions/ownership, we get the same exception. Fixing permission/ownership solved it. Hope it saves someone else a couple of hours ...